# What roll do I call for to resolve feats of strength and other physical challenges?

Tags: call-of-cthulhu

I'm currently running a Call of Cthulhu campaign and I'm trying to determine what to do with something along the lines of feats of strength and whatnot.

I had a character try to crank-start a rundown vehicle and I imagined a feat like that would be difficult and require some sort of roll, but I'm new to the system and I'm sure what type of roll to call for.

Answer (score 8):

In Call of Cthulhu, for straight stat checks you usually have someone roll percentage vs 5 times the relevant stat.  If you are pitting a stat against another stat, you use the Resistance Table (read the CoC rules for that) but it's basically 50% + 5x acting stat - 5x opposing stat.

In this case assign the crank a STR or SIZ and they'd roll against it on the Resistance Table.

That's RAW.  I always hated tables so we'd do a roll of N times stat based on difficulty - 5 x stat is an easy roll, 1 x stat is super hard, and everything in between.  It's fine to make stuff up as the Keeper in CoC.